# Power-outage resilient installation systems

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup, nsis, rollback

There are [many different installation systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software), like Inno Setup, NSIS, or MSI. I know MSI supports rollback, Inno Setup as well (to some extent), but I wasn't able to find anywhere which systems are power-outage/BSOD resilient.

Does Windows Installer automatically rollback failed installation upon reboot, when the installation was interrupted by power outage? And what about the other two installation systems?

Answer (score 1):

Inno doesn't handle rollback on a system failure as nothing (by default) runs on startup (and I expect the same of most non Windows Installer based setups).
It can however recover just fine by running the install again allowing it to carry on as normal.

Comment: Thanks, +1, but how about the MSI?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use MSI, but as it's database based and has a service included in Windows, I expect it can do somethign along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess/hope that MSI uses transacted NTFS and registry on NT6+ and should not be affected by a power outage.

Inno and NSIS use the normal file/registry functions and so all the normal power outage problems would apply.

Comment: Could you please back up your guessing/hoping by a documentation link, or some other evidence? :-) I wasn't able to find any exact document confirming this assumption.

Comment: According to [Alternatives to using Transactional NTFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802690(v=vs.85).aspx) article, Windows Installer is listed as an alternative to the transactional NTFS, which probably means it does not use it at all.